# Developing Android project with static libraries?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, static-libraries

I've cloned Gallery project from source https://android.googlesource.com.

Then I've added it to Eclipse.

This project contains two static libraries (Java files and `Android.mk`). Those libraries are build using `Android.mk` file. Those libraries aren't visible for Eclipse - Classes from those libraries are used in code but it can't find sources for them.

Is there any way to build that application using Eclipse with all benefits of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'static libraries' do you mean jar files? If so, you need to add them to the project build path, under the 'libraries' tab. (Right-click project, select 'Properties', click 'Java Build Path').

Comment: No, they are not jar files. They are Java files + Android.mk (Android Makefile)

Comment: If they are Java, files, just copy them to your project. You don't need the Android.mk to build in Eclipse.

Comment: But this will break my building toolchain. I would like to be able to build my Android ROM and to debug / develop application in Eclipse.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't build the system in Eclipse. You can edit the code, but you still need to build using make, etc. This is the official guide for using Eclipse with AOSP: http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Comment: I'm trying to have: source ready to be build, but also ability to use Eclipse in development of single Application.

Comment: The easiest way is to checkout the whole thing and use the instructions I linked to edit in Eclipse. Then just edit the gallery app and don't touch other code. Most platform apps cannot be built independently without some modifications. You might be able to extract just the necessary dependencies and use the platform jars, but you might need to edit the build files a bit.

Comment: Actually my problem was quite simple. I had to add additional folder with sources. In `Java build path -> source -> Add Folder...'